# double dimension array dynamic c#

Tags: c#, python-3.x

I'm a python developer and I would like to convert this following code on C# :

```
#long version
tab = []
for i in range(n):
    tab.append([])
    for j in range(n):
        tab[i].append(0)

#short version
tab = [[0]*n for _ in range(n)]
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Make an attempt yourself, and if you have issues, then ask us for help.

Comment: There isn't a simple translation because C# looks at data so differently.   I think I would recommend using a ````List<>```` over an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want dynamic list size I recommend using the C# generic `List<>` collection type.

In this example, I create a list of a list of ints. This is very much the same as a dynamic array of array of ints (if that was possible in C#).

Both the `List<List<int>>` and the `List<int>` can grow and change in size.  For the purposes of my example, I hard coded the the number of elements in each list but it doesn't have to be fixed.

Here's an example code where I make a List of List of ints:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<List<int>> stuff = new List<List<int>>();

        for (int count = 0; count < 3; count++)
        {
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            list.AddRange(new int[] { 1, 2, 4 });
            stuff.Add(list);
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"stuff is a list of {stuff.Count} items");
        Console.WriteLine($"the first list item in stuff has {stuff[0].Count} items");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Here's the output:

```
stuff is a list of 3 items 
the first list item in stuff has 3 items
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This code can be easily translated to C# because in C# arrays are initialized with zeros:

```
var n = 3;
var tab = new int[n, n];
```

Comment: ok thanks, i'll test this now

Comment: what is the equivalent of append in c# ? push ?

Comment: Arrays like I used in my answer doesn't have append/push methods - they have fixed size. If you need dynamically extandable list use `List<int>` instead and it's `Add` method

Answer (score 0):

I tested this it works but it's not dynamic like the python method :

```
int[][] newtab = new int[4][];
newtab[0] = new int[4] { 0,0,0,0 };
newtab[1] = new int[4] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
newtab[2] = new int[4] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
newtab[3] = new int[4] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };


for (int i = 0; i < newtab.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < newtab[i].Length; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(newtab[i][j]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```